# What key will skip to end of autocomplete?

Tags: komodo

I just started using Komodo by way of VS and Aptana.  When I'm doing anything with parentheses, it helpfully autocompletes the closing parenthesis like in Aptana.  My instinct is to then press TAB to skip to the end of the line, but that doesn't seem to work in Komodo. I've looked through the key bindings several times but I don't know what the action I'm looking for is actually called, so it doesn't do any good.  How do I skip to the end of the autocomplete? The image below shows what the editor looks like when I want to skip to the end of the outlined parenthesis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/editor.html — "Cursor movement (e.g. moving over the soft character with the right-arrow) "hardens" soft characters."

Depending on what OS you're on, I expect the "go to end of line" character movement would have the same effect for multiple characters at once (i.e. the full autocomplete). Apple-right-arrow on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but press the "end" button to skip to the end of a line. This should do what you're asking.

Comment: Is there an "End" key on your keyboard, or are you referring to a button in the UI?